# Can I travel to france with a Fiktionsbescheinigung abs 81 4

Tags: international-travel, germany, europe, france

I have a valid Fiktionsbescheinigung with the 3rd box checked. 81 Abs 4 .can I go to France and come back without a problem or not?

Comment: Fiktionsbescheinigung?

Comment: @NeanDerThal It's a temporary resident permit for Germany.

Comment: Yes , you guys know whither I have the right to travel or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

From the [Berlin Service Portal](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326233/en/):

> this case, the residence permit and all supplementary regulations (also regarding the stipulations concerning gainful employment) remain in force until a decision has been made in relation to the application. **Journeys abroad and re-entry into the area of the Republic are possible with a valid [Fiktionsbescheinigung]  in accordance with § 81 Section 4 of the Residence Act.**

Comment: So basically I have the right to go to france with no problem

Comment: @WijdaneAarroub Yes.